# Android studio permissions not working

Tags: java, android, permissions, ads

So I made a simple 0-100kmh calculator app nothing special, but my ads wont work I suppose thats because they need permissions and I just can't get them to work. Maybe I need to import class for it? Thank you for your time.

```
package com.example.lipa.kalkulator_0_100;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.Manifest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {




    EditText Snaga;
    EditText Masa;
    RadioButton FWD;
    RadioButton RWD;
    RadioButton AWD;
    private AdView mAdView;


    TextView Rezultat;


    String oper ="";

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-5747237038129871~4158977342");
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                        1);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }



        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false))
        {
            finish();
        }


        //elementi
        FWD = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.fwd);
        RWD = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rwd);
        AWD = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.awd);
        Masa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Masa);
        Snaga = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Snaga);
        Rezultat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rezultat);


    }



    public void onRadioClicked(View view) {
        double masa_unos;
        double snaga_unos;
        double result = 0;
        double rezpo;
        double rezkr = 0;

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Masa.getText().toString())
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(Snaga.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unesite vrijednosti!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        masa_unos = Double.parseDouble(Masa.getText().toString());
        snaga_unos = Double.parseDouble(Snaga.getText().toString());
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton)view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.fwd:
                oper= "Go";
                if(checked)
                    result = (masa_unos+75) / snaga_unos;
                    rezkr = result;
                break;
            case R.id.rwd:
                oper= "Go";
                if(checked)
                    result = (masa_unos+75) / snaga_unos;
                    rezpo = (result*0.076);
                    rezkr = result-rezpo;
                break;
            case R.id.awd:
                oper= "Go";
                if(checked)
                    result = (masa_unos+75) / snaga_unos;
                    rezpo = (result*0.11478);
                    rezkr = result-rezpo;

                break;
        }
            Rezultat.setText(String.format("%.2f sec", rezkr));
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Your Activity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback

Comment: And For Internet runtime permission is not required only dangerous permission requires At runtime ..

Comment: Can you explain little bit more please. I'm new at programming.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what I need to remove/add?

Comment: In your Main Activity you need to  add implements  ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/system/runtimepermissions check the sample code from here

Comment: It's not helping huh can you write that code for me please?

Comment: Can I know which permission that ads needed ?

Comment: It needs Internet and access network state

Comment: Then in that case you don't need to ask for Runtime permissions just you can add those permissions in your Android manifest file

Comment: You can check this doc link  https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html